# how to make a Timer.schedule() for specific hours and minutes?

Tags: java, timer, scheduled-tasks

i tried to make the `schedule()` method wait till a specific hour and minute
comes and start to execute the task but it didnt work
because the method `schedule()` doesnt take hours and minutes
as an argument, what is the replacment for this method? i'm i supposed make schedule for hours
then when the hour comes the program check the minutes? then if both are correct 
it will start executing or what?

P.S
for making things easier to understand, how to make something similier to this
:

schedule(new TimerClass(), ***desired hours***, ***desired minutes***)?

Comment: Are the hours and minutes relative from _now_?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to such a hardcoding.Testing hour then minutes.Just schedule the task like below.
The task given below will execute after one hour and will be repeated in each 30000ms.If you need execution only once then cancel the time after first execution like using t.cancel() and also convert Hour+minute to ms to put the scheduled time

```
 TimerTask scanTask;
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer t = new Timer();


scanTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                         //do your task here    

                    }
               });
        }};

t.schedule(scanTask, 1*60*60*1000, 30000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule for a particular clock time (rather than a delay from current time), here are some options:

- Use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), if you're doing this enough to justify the additional library. Quartz makes it easy to specify clock times, and supports scheduling recurring events.
- Otherwise, at the time you're scheduling, compute the difference between the current time and the desired time. (Use the Calendar class to create clock times, convert to Dates, and getMillis().) Feed the difference to Timer -- or ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.